# file read from and file written to are not same

Tags: c, fflush

I am trying to read contents of a file that is some 3KB into a buffer and then writing the contents of the buffer into another file. The file in which data is written into contains only a part of data that is written into it. Its size is around 1KB. How to write the remaining data?

```
fp1 = fopen("a.txt","rb");
fp2 = fopen("b.txt","wb");

fread(buffer, 1, BUFFER_SIZE,fp1);//reading from file pointed to by fp1
//BUFFER_SIZE = 3KB
fwrite(buffer, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, fp2);//writing into a file pointed to by fp2
```

Will a fflush after fwrite do that for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is *no* guarantee that `fread` will give you all the bytes you asked for. It can give you less, which is what the return code is for.

You need to use the return code to figure out how much information to send to the `fwrite`.

And that checking of return codes extends to the `fopen` calls as well - there's no guarantees that the open will work.

By way of example, the following complete program will attempt to copy up to 3K from one file to another:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main (void) {
    FILE *fp1, *fp2;
    char buff[3*1024];
    int bytesRead;

    // Open both files.

    if ((fp1 = fopen ("a.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf ("Error %d opening a.txt\n", errno);
        return 1;
    }
    if ((fp2 = fopen ("b.txt", "w")) == NULL) {
        printf ("Error %d opening b.txt\n", errno);
        fclose (fp1);
        return 1;
    }

    // Transfer only up to buffer size.

    if ((bytesRead = fread (buff, 1, sizeof (buff), fp1)) == 0) {
        // Check error case.

        if (ferror (fp1)) {
            printf ("Error reading a.txt\n");
            fclose (fp1);
            fclose (fp2);
            return 1;
        }
    }

    // Attempt transfer to destination file.

    if (fwrite (buff, 1, bytesRead, fp2) != bytesRead) {
        printf ("Error writing b.txt\n");
        fclose (fp1);
        fclose (fp2);
        return 1;
    }

    // Close all files to finish up.

    fclose (fp1);
    fclose (fp2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fread()` *only* returns a short item count if an error occurs or end-of-file is reached.  There is no point retrying the `fread()` - if end-of-file was reached, there is no more data; and if an error occured, the value of the file position indicator is indeterminate.  This is in contrast with the typical underlying low-level functions like `read()`, which *can* return short reads without it being an error.

Answer (score 3):

`fflush(fp2)` or `fclose(fp2)` will move the pending, buffered bytes to disk.

Comment: you mean to say that fwrite is always unreliable without fflush or fclose?

Comment: `fwrite()` is reliable, but buffering is involved by default for overall efficiency for the vast majority of program usages.  If what you are doing does not need buffering, you could use `setbuf()` on the file after opening it to disable the buffering.

Comment: @ajaybidari: Note that if the process exits cleanly (by returning from `main()` or calling `exit()`), all open streams with unwritten buffered data are flushed and all open streams are closed.  Note that even with `fflush()` or `fclose()`, writes may be buffered by the operating system and so they may not be durable after a system crash without calling some OS-specific sync function.